# jqGrid JSON map not reading INDEX value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid, json-deserialization

I'm trying to display a jqGrid using jquery 1.6.2.mins, and the latest jqGrid - jqGrid 4.5.4.

My project setup is:
ASP.NET - MVC2 using Visual Studio 2010.
Framework is .Net 4.0

Problem: In my C# class I'm adding all the rows from the database that I will be using at one point or another.  I just want to display two rows initially (`NAME`, `DESCRIPTION`).

The jqGrid displays two rows but its displaying my id's row in the first where it should be displaying what the Description column displays.  So basically whats happening is, the rows are being shifted to the right, and my column mapping its not working.  `NAME = 'NAME_TXT'`, but for some reason what I'm getting in the display is `NAME = ID`;

```js
colNames: ['NAME', 'DESCRIPTION'],
colModel: [
    { name: 'NAME', index: 'NAME_TXT', align: 'left' },
    { name: 'DESCRIPTION', index: 'DESCRIPTION_TXT', align: 'left'}
],
```

I will also like to know how can I display everything that the JSON data is getting back from the C# code, how do I display the object in `console.log("JSON DATATYPE: " + $datatype)`, something like that.

Thank you.

JavaScript Code:

```js
$(function () {
    $grid = $("#grid");

    $grid.jqGrid({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/csc/devapp1/Home/LinqGridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['NAME', 'DESCRIPTION'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'NAME', index: 'NAME_TXT', align: 'left' },
            { name: 'DESCRIPTION', index: 'DESCRIPTION_TXT', align: 'left'}],    
        sortname: 'NAME_TXT',
        sortorder: "desc",
        repeatitems: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        height: '500px',
        autowidth: true});
});
```

C# code:

```cs
public ActionResult LinqGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var context = new CSCEntities();

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = 1,
        page = page,
        records = context.tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar.Count(),
        rows = context.tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar.AsEnumerable().Select(n =>
            new { n.QUICKFIX_ID, 
                cell = new string[] { 
                    n.QUICKFIX_ID.ToString(), 
                    n.NAME_TXT.ToString(), 
                    n.DESCRIPTION_TXT.ToString(), 
                    n.INSTRUCTIONS_TXT.ToString(),
                    n.TYPE_TXT.ToString(),
                    n.FIXLINK_TXT.ToString()} 
            }).ToArray()
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Other C# code I tried in the past that didn't work:

```
public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        CSCEntities entities = new CSCEntities();
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = entities.tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var jsonData = new {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,

            rows = (
                from entity in entities.tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar

                select new {
                    id = entity.QUICKFIX_ID,
                    cell = new string[] {

                        entity.NAME_TXT.ToString(),
                        entity.DESCRIPTION_TXT.ToString(), 
                        entity.QUICKFIX_ID.ToString(),
                        entity.INSTRUCTIONS_TXT.ToString() }
                    }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you posted have many problems on both client and the server side. I'll mention only some of the problems.

Your main problem is in the server code which you use. You use currently in the server code

```
...
new { n.QUICKFIX_ID, 
    cell = new string[] { 
        n.QUICKFIX_ID.ToString(), 
        n.NAME_TXT.ToString(), 
        n.DESCRIPTION_TXT.ToString(), 
        n.INSTRUCTIONS_TXT.ToString(),
        n.TYPE_TXT.ToString(),
        n.FIXLINK_TXT.ToString()} 
}
...
```

which seems should be changed to

```
...
new {
    id = n.QUICKFIX_ID, 
    cell = new [] { 
        n.NAME_TXT.ToString(), 
        n.DESCRIPTION_TXT.ToString()
    }
}
...
```

You should additionally to consider to remove `.AsEnumerable()` or to move it after `select` are applied.

First of all `index` property have only some meaning in *server side sorting*. The server code which you posted don't use `sidx` and `sord` parameters. So you should *remove* all `index` properties from the `colModel`. If no `index` property specified jqGrid uses the same value for `index` as the value `name` property. It's what one need in 99% of scenarios. So I recommend you to specify no `index` property. Because you use array format of items (`cell = new string[] {...}` the choice of `name` property is free. You can use `name: 'NAME_TXT'` in the same way like `name: 'NAME'`. If the names of columns in the database are `NAME_TXT` and `DESCRIPTION_TXT` I would personally prefer to use the same values for `name`.

Default value of `align` property is already `'left'`. So it's better to remove unneeded `align: 'left'` property from `colModel`. The value of `'500px'` for `height` option is wrong. Correct values are the string `"auto"` or the string `"100%"` or any *integer* value like `height: 500`. I personally like to use `height: "auto"`.

jqGrid don't have `contentType` option. If you need to specify `contentType` of HTTP request you should use `{ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" }` instead. The option `repeatitems` don't exist and it should be removed. On the other side I would recommend you to add two other options in jqGrid: `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true`.

One more very important option is `rowNum`. It's default value is `20`. The value will be sent to the server as the value of `rows` parameter (see parameters of `LinqGridData`). The server should return only `rows` items of data sorted by `sidx`. If the server returns more as `rows` items (more as 20 items) jqGrid will still display only the first `rows` items (only the first 20 items). Typically grid have the pager bar at the bottom or at the top of grid. So the user can go to another page. You don't use currently neither `page` nor `toppager` option. As the result the grid will contains up to 20 rows, and the user will have no possibility to use paging to see the rest data. **I recommend you to use `pager` or `toppager: true` option or at least you should include `rowNum: 10000` option to display up to 10000 rows returned from the server**.

If you don't implemented *server side* paging, sorting and filtering of data you can return *all* data to jqGrid, but use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. In the case all data will be saved locally, `datatype` will be changed to `"local"` after the first loading from the server and the user will able to sort data *locally* or to use paging without require that you write any additional code. It's very practical option if the data which you need display (`tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar`) are not too large.

Comment: Oleg, not all the changes you suggested work.  So what I was trying to do was: 
    1. I needed to display two columns in the table, the table only 
       has about 20 rows total.  So displaying everything at once 
       was never an issue.
    2. I needed to use the information on the additional columns to 
       display as a tooltip or a dialog.
So I tried removing the AsEnumerable() function call in my server side code and it broke my grid.  I tried placing it after the select statement as you recomended and it broke my grid as well. Some of your suggestion were helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I also added the server side code that I was previously using before the AsEnumerable() server side code.  That did not work and I don't know why.  I also try changing the datatype to local and that broke my grid as well.